# Hiding sidebar of website in android WebView?

Tags: android, webview

Hiding sidebar of website in android WebView?

I'm trying to open a website in my `WebView`, where it doesn't hide the left sidebar that website contains, whilte visiting the same website from Google Chrome mobile auto hides it,

How I can auto hide it in my `WebView`?

and I can't seems to find any question regarding it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

The website can be found [here](http://musicheed.com/new-releases)

Here are the sample pictures of both my `WebView` and chrome browser.

**My WebView:**

[image]

**Google Chrome Mobile:**

[image]

Comment: Its seems like problem is not about webview, you have to check your mobile layout website.

Comment: but it opens fine in chrome mobile browser?

Comment: Same question here, but found no solution as of today